# Поліцейський, поліцай, поліціянт чи поліціант?

Tags: вживання-слів

У словнику української мови:

- > Поліцейський - Який працює в поліції (у 1 знач.).
- > ПОЛІЦА́Й, я, чол. У дореволюційній Росії та в деяких капіталістичних країнах — особа, що служить у поліції, нижчий чин поліції.
- > ПОЛІЦІА́НТ, ПОЛІЦІЯ́НТ, а, чол., розм. Те саме, що поліцай

Тобто в сучасній мові, коли говоримо про Україну, потрібно вживати лише термін "поліцейський"? Слова поліцай, поліціант, поліціянт стосуються лише дореволюційної Росії та деяких капіталістичніх країн?

Comment: Якщо ви користувалися словником sum.in.ua, то він був виданий у 1980-х роках, отже описує реалії СРСР.

Comment: Див. також: [«Чи варто вживати слово „коп“?»](/q/4166).

Answer (score 7):

Відповідь на це питання знаходимо у [відео-уроці  О. Авраменка](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPKFnUMoCuE). На думку мовознавця, 
**поліцейський** краще не вживати, оскільки мовознавці вважають, що **-ей**  є притаманною частиною не в українській мові, а в російській. Краще вживати **поліціянт**. Однак, саме поліцейський знаходимо у всіх словниках, тому нормативно вживати поліцейський у діловому мовленні, а в розмовному **поліціянт**. Можливо з часом **поліціянт** витіснить **поліцейського**. Щодо **поліцая**, то цей термін є нормативним і виступає синонімом до слова **поліцейський** ([Словник синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%86%D0%B0%D0%B9)):

> **ПОЛІЦА́Й** (особа, що служить у поліції, перев. нижчий чин), ПОЛІЦЕЙСЬКИЙ, ФАРАО́Нзаст., зневажл.,ПОЛІЦІА́НТ[ПОЛІЦІЯ́НТ]заст., розм.;ПОЛІСМЕ́Н.

Однак, цей термін не вібрав в себе семантику поняття сучасного представника поліції і не є поширеним. Тому, найкраще вживати слово **поліцейський** у діловій мові.

Answer (score 2):

Знайшов ще [пояснення](http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/112507/28-Horodenska.pdf?sequence=1) від мовознавця [Катерини Городенської](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0):

> ... прикметник поліцейський утворений не за українським, а російським
> зразком, бо в  ньому перед суфіксом -ськ- використано структурну
> прокладку -ей, пор. російські милицейский, полицейский, армейский та
> ін. В українській літературній мові від іменників на -ія прикметники
> утворюють переважно за допомогою суфіксів -н- (пор.: Біблія –
> біблійний, коаліція – коаліційний) або -ськ- (армія – армійський). Від
> слова поліція органічним для української мови є прикметник поліційний,
> який подають перекладні російсько-українські словники (щоправда, на
> другому місці, після прикметника поліцейський) і який був уживаний,
> пор.:Там його [Кониського] держали під поліційним доглядом... (І.
> Франко); То не поліційний свисток, то свисток спортивний (Пігмаліон,
> перекл. О. Мокровольського); ...всі матеріали про УВО-ОУН з поліційних
> архівів колишньої польської та гітлерівсько-німецької держав...
> опинилися в руках большевиків (П. Мірчук. Нарис історії ОУН).
>
> Так само потрібно замінити і поширену сьогодні не українську назву
> поліцейський, якою іменують особу, що працює в поліції. Зважаючи на
> помітне в мовній практиці намагання утворювати від іменників на -ія
> назви осіб за допомогою суфікса -янт (пор.: коаліція – коаліціянт,
> міліція – міліціянт та ін.), рекомендуємо для вжитку назву поліціянт,
> якою вже послуговуються автори деяких видань, пор.: Патрульні
> поліціянти допомогли оформити всі знайдені речі (Львівська газета,
> 6.10.2015); Бажання стати новими поліцянтами..висловило понад 30 000 українців, які подали заявки нак онкурс (ВВСУкраїна, 25.02.2015).
>
> Отже, українською мовою органічніше вживати поліційний замість
> поліцейський та поліціянт замість поліцейський.

Як бачите, думки мовознавців ще досі різняться.